# Network Inventory Software

Tags: networking, inventory-software

I"m looking for a tool to carry out a network inventory of all the PCs on my domain and not too sure what is the best freeware for this.
 I have found one called Steel Inventories but it only lets you scan up to 25 PCs on the network my network has about 45-50 machines on it.

Comment: not sure this mabe better on server fault or not?

Comment: Ben, it looks like the question has been asked on Sever Fault before quite a bit. Take a look at the search for [network inventory](http://serverfault.com/search?q=network+inventory) on [SF]. I closed your question and left it here; if for some reason none of the solutions in the questions listed on Server Fault work for you, let us know and we could potentially edit your question and move it over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OCSInventory** is the biz - we use it across 2 sites and about 180 PCs. It collates stats on hardware and software installed on a scheduled basis and this is imported automatically into our helpdesk software (GLPI). The app's native environment is a Linux server but there is a Windows package too - details on the site.

http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/en/